# How to code Android 4.0 style section

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

As shown in the new [design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html),

Google showed us a built-in way to display sections.

Is this kind of section a specific Layout? can I "hard-code" previously known sections in a form-like app?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out it was same as before:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section text"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

Comment: I know it is a simple question, but newbies like me find those things hard to find on the docs or wherever.

Thx Richard!